# How to index a loop by year in dataset

Tags: r

My dataset looks like this:

```
Year Risk    Resource Utilization Band    Percent
2014         0                            .25    
2014         1                            .19 
2014         2                            .17 
2014         3                            .31 
2014         4                            .06
2014         5                            .01 
2015         0                            .23 
2015         1                            .21  
2015         2                            .19 
2015         3                            .31 
2015         4                            .06 
2015         5                            .31
```

I am attempting to compare percentage change year to year for the dataset I am working with.  For example 2014 decreased 2% in 2015.  So far, I have created a loop that puts each by year into bins and runs the calculation.  The issue I am having is that the loop is indexing each loop as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfEG8.png) so I have a bunch of repeating [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfEG8.png)s next to my calculations.  Here is the code I have been using, any help is much appreciated

```
Results.data <- data.frame()

head(data)

percent <- 0
baseyear <- 0
nextyear <- 0
bin <- 0
yearPlus1 <-0
bin2 <-0
percent1 <-0
percent2 <-0
percentDif <-0


for(i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  percent[i] <- data$PERCENT[i]
  baseyear[i] <- as.numeric(data$YEAR_RISK[i])
  bin[i] <- as.numeric(data$RESOURCE_UTILIZATION_BAND[i])

  #print(percent[i])
  #print(baseyear[i])
  #print(bin[i])
}

for (k in 1:nrow(data))
{

  for (j in 1:nrow(data))
  {
    yearPlus1 <- as.numeric(baseyear[j])-1
    firstYear <- as.numeric(baseyear[k])
    bin2 <-bin[j]
    bin1 <- bin[k]
    percent1 <- as.numeric(percent[k])
    percent2 <- as.numeric(percent[j])

    if(firstYear==yearPlus1 && bin1==bin2)
    {
      percentDif <- percent2 - percent1
      print(percentDif)


      Results.data <- rbind(Results.data, c(percentDif))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data? And what your desired output is for that sample input?

Comment: Yes. I just edited my original post to give an example of the data set. So basically I am trying to compare each rub frequency by year so from 2014 to 2015 rub frequency decreased by 2%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can use grouping and vectorization to avoid loops. Here's an example using the `dplyr` package.

The code below first sorts by `Year_Risk` so that the data are ordered properly by time. Then we group by `Resource_Utilization_Band` so that we can get results separately for each level of `Resource_Utilization_Band`. Finally, we calculate the difference in `Percent` from year to year. The `lag` function returns the previous value in a sequence. (Instead of `lag`, we could have done `Change = c(NA, diff(Percent))` as well.) All of these operations are chained one after the other using the `dplyr` chaining operator (`%>%`).

(Note that when I imported your data, I also changed your column names by adding underscores to make them legal R column names.)

```
library(dplyr)

# Year-over-year change within each Resource_Utilization_Band
# (Assuming your starting data frame is called "dat")
dat %>% arrange(Year_Risk) %>%
  group_by(Resource_Utilization_Band) %>%
  mutate(Change = Percent - lag(Percent))
```

> ```
>    Year_Risk Resource_Utilization_Band Percent Change
> 1       2014                         0    0.25     NA
> 2       2014                         1    0.19     NA
> 3       2014                         2    0.17     NA
> 4       2014                         3    0.31     NA
> 5       2014                         4    0.06     NA
> 6       2014                         5    0.01     NA
> 7       2015                         0    0.23  -0.02
> 8       2015                         1    0.21   0.02
> 9       2015                         2    0.19   0.02
> 10      2015                         3    0.31   0.00
> 11      2015                         4    0.06   0.00
> 12      2015                         5    0.31   0.30
> ```

Comment: That works perfectly and is much easier than how I was doing it. Thanks so much